# SOAPUI: How to find node count in JSON response

Tags: json, soapui

I have JSON response below in SOAP UI:-
I need to find number of JSON Nodes in this JSON.
I tried with JSONPATH Count but it doesn't give accurate result.
Here 8 nodes are there which is expected as output.

```
<data contentType="text/plain" contentLength="772"><![CDATA[[{
    "EmployeeId": "99",
    "EmployeeName": "Doe",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "88",
    "EmployeeName": "John",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "999",
    "EmployeeName": "Doe",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "888",
    "EmployeeName": "John",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "777",
    "EmployeeName": "Keerthi",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "666",
    "EmployeeName": "Keerthi",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "1234",
    "EmployeeName": "Sushant",
    "Role": "Doctor"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "107",
    "EmployeeName": "John8",
    "Role": "LabTech"
}]]]></data>
```

How to find Node Counts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may extract the list and use `size()` method on it get the count using `groovy script`.

For example:

```json
def employees = '''
[
    {
        "EmployeeId": "88",
        "EmployeeName": "John",
        "Role": "Dr"
    },
    {
        "EmployeeId": "999",
        "EmployeeName": "Doe",
        "Role": "Dr"
    }
]'''

def employeeList = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( employees )
println employeeList.size()
```

*Output* is 2 which is expected.

**Update:**

*If you want to the specific data that you provided*, here you go.

Since the data is not directly json type, i.e., wrapped in `cdata` which is part of xml.
So first need to extract json data from xml then apply size to get the count.

```groovy
def xml = '''
<data contentType="text/plain" contentLength="772"><![CDATA[[{
    "EmployeeId": "99",
    "EmployeeName": "Doe",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "88",
    "EmployeeName": "John",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "999",
    "EmployeeName": "Doe",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "888",
    "EmployeeName": "John",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "777",
    "EmployeeName": "Keerthi",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "666",
    "EmployeeName": "Keerthi",
    "Role": "Dr"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "1234",
    "EmployeeName": "Sushant",
    "Role": "Doctor"
},
{
    "EmployeeId": "107",
    "EmployeeName": "John8",
    "Role": "LabTech"
}]]]></data>'''
def data = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def list = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( data.toString())
log.info list.size()
```

You may also assert it using :
`assert 8 == list.size(), "Employee count is not matching"`

Comment: Ok glad to know. Just for your information adding comment. Gave an example with fixed data to make it easy for testing. You can the response to `xml` variable so that it works dynamically instead of fixed data.