# SoapUI JSONPath assertion based on count of returned items

Tags: soapui, assertions, jsonpath

In the response to my request I get a JSON list of items

```
{
"Id": 111,
"Name": "aaa"
},
{
"Id": 222,
"Name": "bbb"
}
```

I need to assert that in my response there are at least 5 items. When using JSONPath Count I can only check for the exact value using $..*. Unfortunately I don't know the exact number of items returned and as long as more than 5 are in the response everything is ok. Can I do that using any of the JSONPath assertions?

Comment: Apparently there is a JSONPath Count assertion: http://readyapi.smartbear.com/structure/assertions/property/json/count/start

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623183/soapui-how-to-find-node-count-in-json-response/35626696#35626696) to see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems I have to use Script Assertion for that:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def ParsedMessage = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
assert !(ParsedMessage.isEmpty())
assert ParsedMessage.Id != null
assert ParsedMessage.Name != null
assert ParsedMessage.size() > 30
```